# mysqlnd driver in PHP 5.3.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to get the mysqlnd driver setup on php5.3.2 (default version) on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). The PHP docs say that mysqlnd is compiled by default in the 5.3 builds. But I haven't been able to find a way to make it part of the aptitude build.

Comment: Questions that have answers involving how to update apt are better asked on serverfault.  This is problem with setting up a web stack, not with programming on one.

Answer (score 4):

add this line to sources in the package manager

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe
```

Then install package `php5-mysqlnd`

NOTE: If you are running Zend Server/CE, this is potentially dangerous as installation will remove several zend server packages, experiment with this as your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the docs say it's enabled by default on the Windows versions, and on Unix PHP uses the older MySQL Client Library instead ([as documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php)). But that's no guarantee that Ubuntu enabled it in their default build. As far as I can, it's nowhere to be found in Ubuntu/Lucid. There's no package for it on the repositories, and `php -i` and `phpinfo()` both do not list it as a built-in module on my Lucid x64 Server install.

Most likely you'll have to get Ubuntu's source .deb for MySQL and roll your own compile with mysqlnd activated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this blogpost](http://blog.ahughes.org/?p=602) to install both `php5-mysqlnd` and phpmyadmin